# Can't social sign in with Firebase Auth on Cordova app

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Google and Facebook login with Firebase on my Cordova app. 
I followed this guide:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

But I still get this error:

```
auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment
```

This is my code:

```
      var provider = new window.parent.firebaseRef.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      window.parent.firebaseRef.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;

      }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;

        Materialize.toast(errorMessage, 4000);
      });
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version Firebase JS? Keep in mind this is only supported for Android and iOS.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of firebase.js file. What is only supported for Android and iOS? What did you mean?

Comment: Cordova supports other platforms (not just Android and iOS) but Firebase Auth only support the latter. I wanted to make sure you are not using another platform.

Comment: Oh, got it. I'm working on an Android app.